# PTIJ: Cookies for Elijah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The prophet Elijah told the woman:

> וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אֵלֶ֤יהָ אֵלִיָּ֙הוּ֙ אַל־תִּ֣ירְאִ֔י בֹּ֖אִי עֲשִׂ֣י כִדְבָרֵ֑ךְ אַ֣ךְ עֲשִׂי־לִֽי־מִ֠שָּׁ֠ם עֻגָ֨ה קְטַנָּ֤ה בָרִֽאשֹׁנָה֙ וְהוֹצֵ֣את לִ֔י וְלָ֣ךְ וְלִבְנֵ֔ךְ תַּעֲשִׂ֖י בָּאַחֲרֹנָֽה׃

> Don't be afraid and first make me a small cookie. [1 Kings 17:13]

Did Elijah really keep digital cookies to identify all the people he came in contact with, to improve their experience in navigating through life?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Unless they gave permission for him to look into their private life, he couldn’t look into their future.

Comment: No, you put it on a plate with a glass of milk by the Hanukkah shrub. It's his snack after he delivers the presents.

Comment: @PaulWalker this is what I thought it was a pun on lol

Answer (score 1):

As we know, one can only obtain Ruach Hakodesh with Simcha.

Eliyahu Hanavi was a great cookie lover, who followed the famous Israeli dictum

"Ein Ein Ein Simcha, Bli Bli Bli Oogiyah".

Therefore Eliyahu askes the woman to give him a cookie so that he could gain Ruach Hakodesh and pray to Hashem for a miracle to help her.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Yaakov took a cookie from Eliyahu.

וְזָכַרְתִּי אֶת בְּרִיתִי יַעֲקוֹב וְאַף אֶת בְּרִיתִי יִצְחָק וְאַף אֶת בְּרִיתִי אַבְרָהָם אֶזְכֹּר וְהָאָרֶץ אֶזְכֹּר (ויקרא כ"ו, מ"ב). וברש"י ד"ה וזכרתי את בריתי יעקוב, בחמשה מקומות נכתב מלא ואליהו חסר, בחמשה מקומות יעקב נטל אות משמו של אליהו ערבון שיבוא ויבשר גאולת בניו ע"כ.
ובגור אריה בד"ה יעקב נטל אות משמו וז"ל, אבל יש לומר כי הנותן ערבון נותן לו כף יד, כדכתיב (משלי ו', א' – ג') בְּנִי אִם עָרַבְתָּ לְרֵעֶךָ תָּקַעְתָּ לַזָּר כַּפֶּיךָ וכו' לֵךְ הִתְרַפֵּס , לך והתר פס (פירוש, התר לו פס יד כדי לשלם לו). ויש חמשה אצבעות בכף היד, לכך נטל בחמשה מקומות הוי"ו של אליה, כאילו כפו, שהוא חמשה אצבעות הם אצל יעקב, והאצבע דומה לוי"ו, לכך הוי"ו מן אליה חסר, והיא נתונה ליעקב. ובמסכת אהלות (פ"א מ"ח) מונה שלשים אברים בפיסת יד של אדם, וחמשה וואוי"ן הם שלשים, שלקח יעקב פיסת ידו של אליהו לערבון שיבוא ויגאל את בניו ע"כ.

Comment: Translate please

Comment: @Moishe Yaakov took the *yud* from Eliyahu's name in 5 places, comprising an entire hand, according to the Maharal.